# Laravel attempt() method is undefined (JWT)

Tags: laravel, validation, authentication

I am trying to authenticate users in Laravel using JWT. In my auth controller I have this login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $jwt_token = null;

        $input = $request->only("email", "password");

        if (!$jwt_token = auth('users')->attempt($input)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'invalid email or password'
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $jwt_token,
        ]);
    }
```

But the attempt method is "undefined". The same happens if I use

```
auth('users')->JWTAuth::attempt($input)
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the actual error when posting questions like this, in the future. When testing I can see that the error is `"Undefined property: Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard::$JWTAuth"` - So it complains about a property, not a method.

Comment: Which library you are using for JWT authentication?

Comment: Got it working now, but it's tymon/jwt-auth.

Comment: @Aejg i am facing the same issue here, how did you figure it out?

Comment: @LakwinChandula I asked around, and the consensus was that it’s not uncommon for VS code (the IDE I was using) to not recognise all commands (hence the red squiggles) as it only does limited analysis of the code to work out such things. The fact that my code worked fine led me to believe this was likely the case.

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted the answer if it didn't solve your problem. Over a year later, Intellephense plugin in Vscode still doesn't recognize the attempt() method. Accepting it makes others with the same issue lose even more time to try and figure out why it doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be called as `auth('users')->JWTAuth::attempt($input);`

Try with: `auth('users')->attempt($input);`

Comment: It still gives me the same error, attempt() is underlined in red, but strangely the login functionality works fine?

Comment: When I hover over it it says: "Undefined method 'attempt'. intelephense(1013)"

Comment: The attempt() method is still underlined, but actually works fine. People have told me it will likely be down to VSCode's intelephense not recognising the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it like this

Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));

Comment: But it doesn't solve the problem. If you'd have read through the other comments you'd have seen he's using PHP Intellephense in Vscode. That plugin generates the error (even though the code works) and up to now it still has the same issue.